# Reading CSV displaying outcome in different format

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

Pandas read_csv() displays the dataset view like in string format. This has started to happen recently.Any idea how to fix?
Thanks

[image]
This is the display I am trying to get back
[image]
This is the current view.

Comment: If it is jupyter, have you tried typing `cars` instead of `print(cars)`?

Answer (score 2):

In Jupyter, you either need to simply run `cars` or `display(cars)`. `print(cars)` calls the dataframe's `__repr__` function, which returns a string, and then prints it, which inhibits Jupyter's ability to nicely and interactively format it.